# Visual Studio debugger not working with Chrome, but working with IE

Tags: visual-studio-2010, google-chrome, visual-studio-debugging

VS does not step into the breakpoints I set when I use Chrome to test. The same breakpoints are stepped into without any issues when I use IE. I'm sure the code is not unreachable. Any ideas why this could be happening?

Comment: Are you debugging Javascript?